# Unassigned record from a BookList not showing up in available BookList for certain users

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to react and have been working on a project. I have 2 lists(not a data type). One is for assigned books, one is for available books. i get the list data from an api call. When i remove a book from the assigned list and search for it in the available books, for some users, it doesn't show up. For Eg, If i unassign Book A From User 1 and search for it in the available book list, it doesn't show up. This is happening only for a few users.

Since it is a work project, i am unable to post the code.
Any kind of help or suggestions as to how i should solve are welcome.

Comment: No code pretty much equals no debugging help. Please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible Code Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that we can help with. We can't help debug code we can't see. It needn't be any proprietary work code, just code that accurately reproduces the issue you have.

Comment: OK.. I will try to replicate it and post it with the question. Thank you.